# Problem with vertical spacing of equations in itemize after the first \item

Tags: spacing, equations, lists, itemize

I found one similar thread here ([Removing strange vertical space after first (customized) \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132701/removing-strange-vertical-space-after-first-customized-item)), but I still could not resolve my problem. Please help.

Description of the problem:

1. I used beamer class.
2. In a frame, in itemize environment, if the text after the first \item is short, then the numbered equations are placed equidistantly in vertical direction. Up till now, no problem.
3. However, if the text after the first \item is long, then the spacing of numbered equations are off. The vertical space after the first equation is unintendedly larger than that between the second and third equations.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item blah
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c=d
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah:
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c=d
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never stack math display environments; instead of consecutive `equation` environments use `gather`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item blah
\begin{gather}
a=b\\
b=c\\
c=d
\end{gather}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah:
\begin{gather}
a=b\\
b=c\\
c=d
\end{gather}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to color math, the correct procedure is to add

```
\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=magenta}
\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=blue}
```

before `\begin{document}`. Acting on `\everymath` or `\everydisplay` doesn't guarantee correct results.

Comment: In using gather environment, I could not colour (automatically) the math expressions and equations anymore with: \everymath{\color{blue}} and 
\everydisplay{\color{magenta}}. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @ThanhNguyen I added the way to get colors in math

Comment: Yes, I am searching for the answer. This problem is often met problem and the answer should be somewhere in this website.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen The two lines of code I added *are* the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Great! But there is still one thing that I would like to ask: With your added solution, the number of the equations in gather environment is also coloured in magenta. Could it be coloured in different colour?

Comment: @ThanhNguyen That warrants a new question with all the details.

Comment: Should `\begin{equation} \only<1>{a=b}\only<2>{b=c} \end{equation}` be avoided too? I noticed the same problem as the OP, solved by using `gather` instead of `equation` (even though in this case only one equation is displayed at a time).

Comment: @anderstood Some problems with displayed equations in beamer are described in the manual