# Align left and right in an enumerate part

Tags: align, enumerate

[image]

I'm new and I don't know a lot of things about latex.
I don't want to align the equals but
I want to align left the equation and right the description
Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: [Removing strange vertical space after first (customized) \item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132701/17423)

Answer (score 4):

It may be simplest to set this up as a `tabular` environment.

By loading the `array` package, it is straightforward to set up the second column to be in math mode, the third column to be in italics, and the words in the fourth column to be surrounded by bracket. Performing this setup saves quite a bit of typing in the body of the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{l >{$}l<{$} >{\itshape}l >{[}l<{]}}
(a) & P+\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}+P=P & for all $P\in E$.     & Identity \\
(b) & P+(-P)=\mathcal{O}            & for all $P\in E$.     & Inverse \\
(c) & (P+Q)+R=P+(Q+R)               & for all $P,Q,R\in E$. & Associative\\
(d) & P+Q=Q+P                       & for all $P,Q\in E$.   & Commutative \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe you could add a line to make the `\arraystretch` command back to its original value afterwards, so that the other tabular environments to come are not affected.

Comment: @anderstood - The scope of the modified `\arraystretch` ends with `\end{center}`; no need to reset `\arraystretch` explicitly.

Comment: OK great. I'll leave my comment if someone else can learn from it, thanks! Concerning spacing, mighty Mico might have missed [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248613/not-adding-vertical-spacing-to-two-consecutive-environments) :D

Comment: @anderstood - Indeed, I had missed that question. :-)

Comment: I keep forgetting how good `array` is. +1 for yet another application.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward `align*` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) can manage this layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]% Just for this example
\begin{align*}
  \text{(a)} && P + \mathcal{O} &= \mathcal{O} + P = P && \textit{for all $P \in E$.}     && \text{[Identity]}    \\
  \text{(b)} &&        P + (-P) &= \mathcal{O}         && \textit{for all $P \in E$.}     && \text{[Inverse]}     \\
  \text{(c)} &&     (P + Q) + R &= P + (Q + R)         && \textit{for all $P,Q,R \in E$.} && \text{[Associative]} \\
  \text{(d)} &&           P + Q &= Q + P               && \textit{for all $P,Q \in E$.}   && \text{[Commutative]}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]% Just for this example
\end{document}
```

You can add another alignment components `&` if you "don't want to align the equations". I don't think that will be helpful though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]% Just for this example
\begin{align*}
  \text{(a)} &&& P + \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O} + P = P && \textit{for all $P \in E$.}     && \text{[Identity]}    \\
  \text{(b)} &&&        P + (-P) = \mathcal{O}         && \textit{for all $P \in E$.}     && \text{[Inverse]}     \\
  \text{(c)} &&&     (P + Q) + R = P + (Q + R)         && \textit{for all $P,Q,R \in E$.} && \text{[Associative]} \\
  \text{(d)} &&&           P + Q = Q + P               && \textit{for all $P,Q \in E$.}   && \text{[Commutative]}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]% Just for this example
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `align*` as well but you need to move the third `&` in order to answer the OPs question because they want the LHS of the equations aligned rather than the equals signs.